# Match everything between characters in Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to match everything between

> /* ***and*** */

And also include the in between characters.

I currently managed to create a pattern that kind of does this

```
\/\*(.+?)\*\/
```

[Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/2MBabj/1)

But it doesn't match multi line quotes and only matches once.

[image]

How can I improve this pattern to match everything that starts with /* and ends with */ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, which makes the `.` match newlines.

```
Regex rx = new Regex("/\*(.+?)\*/", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: It works properly now! Thank you!